# CSS flex align columns as in newspaper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have such a sample code:

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.item {
  flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 9</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 11</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 13</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 14</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My items are aligned a bit wrong, so `item 2` is to the right of `item 1`, and I need to change it a bit...

It should be like so:

```
item 1 | item 4
item 2 | item 5
item 3 | item 6
```

Every next item should be under the previous item, and must be wrapper into to columns. Is it possible with a plain CSS & HTML ?

JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2vc6dw80/)

Comment: if you want columns like a newspaper, why not use css columns - that's exactly what they're meant for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns, otherwise the only way to do it with flex it to change the direction to column and have a fixed height

Comment: @Pete `flex` is more suitable for my real case.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/av7dq2fj/1/

Comment: If you're fine with defining a fixed height that's fine but don't see why flex is more suitable, columns does exactly what you want with the bonus it calculates the split for you so you get equal height columns and you do not need to define a height on the container: https://jsfiddle.net/f54s106d/ (plus it's much less code!)

Comment: @pete reasons like position of items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit change in your code,

Add `flex-direction: column;` to `.items`, and `flex: 0 1;` to `.item`

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 9</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 11</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 13</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>item 14</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do without height/width specifying?

Comment: Without height and width how you gonna set limit to data flow?

Answer (score 0):

you can add flex-direction:column, so that the next element comes to below of the element .4 will come beside 1 . here is the good article you can go through https://gedd.ski/post/flex-wrap/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parentClass { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: column; border: 1px solid #678596; max-width: 600px; height: 300px;}
.parentClass > div {flex: 1 1 80px; background-color:#678596; margin: 5px; text-align: center; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div class="parentClass">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
      <div>Three</div>
      <div>Four</div>
      <div>Five</div>
      <div>Six</div>
      <div>Seven</div>
      <div>Eight</div>
      <div>Nine</div>
      <div>Ten</div>
  </div>
```